# Yii2 Two onchange event in one dropdown list

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to do 2 onchange event in one dropdownlist. The onchange event are:

1. Show  if user select 'Hourly' option in dropdownlist .
2. Dependent dropdownlist.

Both of the onchange event is successfull but when I combine the onchange event in one dropdownlist, it is not working. Below are my source code:

Javascript:

```js
<script>
    function show(select_item) {
            if (select_item == "Hourly") {
                hiddenDiv.style.visibility='visible';
                hiddenDiv.style.display='block';
                Form.fileURL.focus();
            } 
            else{
                hiddenDiv.style.visibility='hidden';
                hiddenDiv.style.display='none';
            }
        }
</script>
```

_form.php :

```
$form->field($model, 'report_type[]')->dropDownList(
                    ['Hourly' => 'Hourly', 'Daily' => 'Daily', 'Weekly' => 'Weekly', 'Monthly' => 'Monthly'],
                    //onchange for hide div
                    ['onchange' => 'java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'],
                    //onchange for dependent dropdownlist
                    [
                        'prompt'=>'-Choose Report Type-',
                        'onchange'=>'
                            $.post( "index.php?r=report-scheduler/list&report_day="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                            $( "select#reportscheduler-report_day").html( data );
                            });
                    ']);
```

Comment: unclear what you are trying to do, are you asking to bind 2 onchange events to one dropdown? why don't you use a single `onchange` event for both the functionalities, please add complete code and description what are you trying to do

Comment: you are right. Im sorry im still student and newbie. Thanks.